# errors occurs to inserting data into database (php laravel)

Tags: laravel-5

QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'students.information' n'existe pas (SQL: insert into `information` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `mobile`) values (, , , ))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI1df.jpg)

```php
public function insert(Request $request)
{
     $id = $request->input('id'); 
     dd($request->id); 
     $firstname = $request->input('firstname'); 
     $lastname = $request->input('lastname'); 
     $mobile = $request->input('mobile');
     $data = array('id'=>$id,"firstname"=>$firstname,"lastname"=>$lastname,"mobile"=>$mobile); 
     DB::table('information')->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to allow somebody to help you easily, please, include DDL with existing data, your code and expected results. Please have a look [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems like the `information` table does not exist in the students database.

Comment: My database name laravel not students .But it display students..I don't know

Comment: public function insert(Request $request){$id = $request->input('id');
dd($request->id);
$firstname = $request->input('firstname');
$lastname = $request->input('lastname');
$mobile = $request->input('mobile');

$data=array('id'=>$id,"firstname"=>$firstname,"lastname"=>$lastname,"mobile"=>$mobile);

DB::table('information')->insert($data);

Comment: What is configured in your `.env` at `DB_DATABASE` ?

Comment: DB_DATABASE=laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code adn the comments it seems your `.env` is configured for another database.
verify the following entries in your `.env` file are correct.

```
DB_CONNECTION=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

If these are all correct check the references in `config/database.php`

Comment: Yes, I checked as you mentioned above things are correct. but I view same error and the field are return null values

Comment: Ahh i see i think you have 2 issues your query is being executed without any inserts and its executing it on the `students` database. is there any where else in your code you are referencing a database named `students` ?

Comment: Dear Mike, I thank for your suggestion I rectify my problem.